# Bot integration with local repository

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-bots

I am trying to create bot with my local repository created on mac. But integration fails always. I am using simulator for testing. I have also selected simulators from device settings.

But getting following error always-

SSH Known Hosts file path is located at `/Library/Server/Xcode/Config/`ssh_known_hosts
SSH strict host checking is enabled (you can disable this by editing the `SSHStrictHostKeyChecking` key in `/Library/Server/Xcode/Config/xcsbuildd.plist`
Untrusted HTTPS certificates is disabled (you can enable this by editing the `TrustSelfSignedSSLCertificates` key in `/Library/Server/Xcode/Config/xcsbuildd.plist`

```
ab59d95ce4458b340114a7aefb9f16479f05982b refs/heads/master
```

SSH Known Hosts file path is located at `/Library/Server/Xcode/Config/`ssh_known_hosts
SSH strict host checking is enabled (you can disable this by editing the `SSHStrictHostKeyChecking` key in `/Library/Server/Xcode/Config/xcsbuildd.plist`
Untrusted HTTPS certificates is disabled (you can enable this by editing the `TrustSelfSignedSSLCertificates` key in

```
/Library/Server/Xcode/Config/xcsbuildd.plist
```

Do I need to generate ssh key?

I have generated ssh key also but how can I add it for local repository on my mac

Plz help if u have any idea.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you pointing bot to a git via https, so these messages are not errors, they are warnings. I have two bots now and they goes to our internal git server by https, and successfully fetching sources and *displays this message anyway*.

As you said, your **integration** fails. If bot can't get sources, it will write that **checkout** sources failed.

To understand what actually goes wrong you should look through the `Build Failure Log` under the `Logs` tab in the your integration in the Xcode or in the safari. (I would recommend you to look in the safari because if your log is huge, safari will load it much faster than Xcode). Yeah, it's not very comfortable, but it's not very hard. At some point you'll see the git command arguments and, perhaps, error reason a few lines below.

Answer (score 0):

After configuring everything as it should be in Xcode Server, I get two different results.

When I create a bot in Xcode: internal-checkout-error.

When I create a bot in Safari: Works like a charm.

Both with the exact same project, the exact same Xcode Server host.  Apple did more than their usual level of obfuscation, here...